# Design approach for displaying various information in a single page dashboard application using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, razor

I'm creating a dashboard application using ASP.NET MVC and want to show various information related to the user in a single page ( a user dashboard).

Something like this:
[image]

When a user browses the URL of the page, I want to display information such as User's basic info, User addresses etc. Each of the sections in the above picture will display some information related to the user.

I'm confused as to how many controllers, views and models to create.

If we assume the URL to be something like this, `localhost/users/userdashboard` where `users` is the application name and `userdashboard` the controller , how do we load various user information in each of the boxes?

I have considered creating a `controller action` for each one of these information boxes( user's basic info, addresses), but how do I make each one of them load a different view automatically( i,e without the user browsing localhost/users/userdashboard/basicInfo )and asynchronously?

Sorry if I have not explained the problem correctly. I am new to ASP.NET MVC

PS: I am using Razor view engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.

1. Create Different Model Like

   - UserBasicInformation
   - UserRecentActivities
   - UserAddress
   - etc.
2. Now In Controller Create Different Action Like  ( Each return respective Model).

   - GetUserBasicInformation(int UserId)
   - GetUserRecentActivities(int UserId)
   - GetUserAddress(int UserId)
   - Dashboard (int UserId)
3. Now How to render in View  ?  ( On DashBoard)

   - Sync Way

     - Use RenderAction Method and Pass your neccessary information so it will return view ( Partial View)
   - Async Way

     - In this method on DocumentLoad of Jquery call Different Action using $.ajax and get result Html and put it proper Div.

Comment: Thanks. If I use the sync way, then in the main view, I should have something like this : @{Html.RenderAction("GetUserBasicInformation");} , Right?

Comment: Yes. You can also pass route value if you want to pass any specific information to action.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your project and the structure you have in your project.

If you are developing all your views using Strongly Typed Views with View Model for each view, then you can create only one action with one view and pass the data using a heavy view model that has all the information required.

If you want to make it more fine grained, then you can have one base action that renders the dashbaord, and put each section in its own partial view with its own action and include these partial views using the `Html.RenderPartial` in the base view.

If you are following partial rendering or loading the base HTML first then loading the other parts of the page, then you can use the second approach above but instead of using `Html.RenderPartial` you will load the content of the partial view using the `$.Ajax` and set the HTML content of the div that has the part in the base view to the content retrieved from the partial action. this is useful if the data changes according to a filter